# Java Sending Gmail Emails through SMTP, How to merge emails?

Tags: java, smtp, gmail

Hi I am trying to write a program that runs over the course of a week and need debugging info sent to my gmail account so I can check status of the program where ever I go. I have decided to use the Javax.mail library to do so, however does anyone know how I can merge emails when sending? By this I mean like a conversation mode to reduce spam to my email. Instead of sending two emails, I want to be able to do somnething like:
Subject
Subject (2)
Subject (3).
Stacking the emails would be much more cleaner on my end. If anyone knows let me know!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking if there's a way to send multiple email messages over an extended time period, and have all the messages be merged at the receiving end?

If that's the case, the answer is definitely no.

Are you asking if you can accumulate the debugging info into one huge email and not send it until the end? If that's the case, then sure,  go ahead and do that.